# asp.net mvc ways for generating dynamic form fields at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

[image]

this is the more or less the schema i want to generate my dynamic form on based on the fields above. i am going to add the direction , max size, default value  and like wise some more fields in it. i am looking for **recommended**  ways and methods in asp.net mvc for generating dynamic fields at runtime.

1) if i design my own engine for it then how? i am interested on that also but this is the last thing i am looking at. method to apply validation is very important in my scenario

2) any framework that may lessen the working time? or anything else?

Comment: What do you mean by "generating dynamic fields at runtime"?

Comment: i have these fields i want to loop through them and display them in my view based on their datatype and then validate them when the user post there values

Comment: i am basically asking recommended ways for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the generic approach, I don't want to code it for you.

1. Create meta class to describe each field (type, name, maxlength, null value handling, data source for combos, etc.)
2. Load the data from database and preprocess it
3. Populate the `ViewBag` with sanitized values
4. Create helper that will generated the control specific code

   ```
   Html.ControlFor("Name", metadata);
   ```
5. Loop in view over the metadata collection.

which will generate textbox, combobox, etc.

Remeber that MVC form handling works over list of key-values, it's the `Binder` feature that converts it to objects. Saving data won't be difficult (dynamically created INSERT, UPDATE statement, ...).

Comment: i have to change the meta class if some field is added or subtracted from my fields. sorry i didn't add it in my question.

Comment: Create meta classes that will describe the columns, meta class collection will then reflect active fields (after adding/removing) and you will use the collection to generate UI.